# Get just the values from an associative array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple array like the following:

```
    array
      0 => string '101'
      1 => string '105'
      2 => string '103'
```

Desired result:

```
    array(101, 105, 103)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: try function [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, use [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

```
array_values(array('0' => '101', '1' => '105', '2' => '103')); // returns array(101, 105, 103)
```

Edit: (Thanks to @MarkBaker)

If you use `var_dump` on the original array and the "values only" array the output might look exactly the same if the keys are numerical and and ascending beginning from 0. Just like in your example.

If the keys are not consisting of numbers or if the numbers are "random" then the output would be different. For example if the array looks like

```
array('one' => '101', 'two' => '105', 'three' => '103')
```

the output of `var_dump` looks different after converting the array with `array_values`.

Comment: Doesnt seem to work for me. I even tried copying your exact same code and var dumping the results. I still get an associative array :(

Comment: @Jose - That's the way var_dump() shows an array.... do you mean you actually want a string of "array(101,05,103)" ?

Comment: I just want a string of array(101,05,103) so that I can use it in a sql query